# CSS - child font-size using em

Tags: css, font-size

What is the most efficient way to make all nested list items the same size while using an em that is not equal to 1.  For example, I want all li's in this list to be sized to 0.85em of the ul's parent.  Do I have to create a separate class for each "level" of depth?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        li
        {
            font-size: 0.85em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Level 1 item
            <ul>
                <li>Level 2 item
                    <ul>
                        <li>Level 3 item</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should work.

```
li li {font-size: 100%;}
```

Comment: It does, but it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: @Bobby, why is it not the most efficient way?

Comment: Without adding extra markup to your page this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 9):

Use the "rem" unit for font sizing. This fixes the font-inheritance problem.

Johnathan Snook has a [great article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) on this.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed the best method. I can add only you should use fall-back value using pixels. Like this: li {font-size: 8.5px; font-size: 0.85em;} And you should set base font size not on body element as usually but on html.

Comment: @MikeEshva: your css example should be {font-size: 8.5px; font-size: 0.85rem;}

Comment: Note that "rem" is only available on IE9+

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to give the first `<ul>` an id or class, and set the `font-size` there.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer assumes you want all li-elements the same size (you say both that you want the the same size, and different size in the question))

Font-size cascades, so if you just set it on the outer element (say a wrapper div or something), everything inside it will get one step smaller like (I think) you want to.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>
        <ul><li>...</li><li>...</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navigation { font-size: 0.85em; }
```

Comment: The example above works as it should though. Even in IE6, that doesn't support the child selector.

Comment: True - I was working with the HTML he gave us. He didn't specify browser compatibility, so I'm assuming he wants something that adheres to the CSS2.1 spec.

Comment: Where in the question does he say that he wants them to be different sizes?

Comment: "make all nested list items the same size" vs. "all li's in this list to be sized to 0.85em of the ul's parent". I'm leaning towards the first, but I can't be sure, and for some reason people are downvoting my answer, so I'm just trying to clarify.

Comment: Fair enough; I've un-downvoted your answer because this seems like a genuine misunderstanding, and your answer does work. But I think it's quite clear - "make all nested list items the same size" means, I assume, "... as each other". The other quote simply states that they should ALL be the computed value of 0.85em of the base font size - there's no inconsistency that I can see.

Comment: This example is kind of specific; what if one has several lists? A class would work, but is that semantic, or just redundant?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Emil, and would vote him up on this if I had enough rep points (n00b here). I would use a class like he mentions in his first point, so its re-usable in the same document. If you want cross browser and are using the current css spec then I cant suggest a better real world example..... roll on css 3 and the death of IE6 !

Comment: Its how I would do it, and I think it was unfair to mark you down for actually being right and giving good advice

Answer (score -1):

> I want all li's in this list to be sized to 0.85em of the ul's parent

```
body > ul { font-size: 0.85em; }
```

would do that

Answer (score -1):

```
li { font-size: 0.85em; }
li li { font-size: 1em; }
```